# create sceneKit File programmatically (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, file, scenekit

i would like to know if it's possible to make a scn File programmatically in my IOS app..
Or something else because I just want to retrieve a created object in itunes sharing .

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. SCNScene conforms to the NSSecureCoding protocol. Add all of your nodes, then use NSKeyedArchiver as you would on any other object.